# spring boot Configuration autowired doesn't work as dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, autowired

I have a source project, here are some code

```
@Configuration
public class AnalyzeSyntaxServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public AnalyzeSyntaxService analyzeSyntaxService() {
        return new AnalyzeSyntaxService();
    }
}
```

and use it in the source project like this

```
@Autowired
private AnalyzeSyntaxService analyzeSyntaxService;
```

it works well

then I package it as a jar file, and add it to the target project as a dependency in `pom.xml`, and I try to use this above service in the same way

```
@Autowired
private AnalyzeSyntaxService analyzeSyntaxService;
```

but it's null, why?

Comment: Your configuration scan the `AnalyzeSyntaxServiceConfig` package?

Comment: i think it does since it works well in the source project

Comment: Did you register `AnalyzeSyntaxServiceConfig` with Spring?

Comment: @phani all related code are here, which is come from the official spring boot tutorial

Comment: With in a Spring Boot app, it automatically detects the package and scans all classes in that package. When you use that project as a dependency module in a separate project, you will have to register `@Configuration` class with Spring.

Comment: could you post an answer in detail, some codes or tutorials link are welcome @phani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the package names different between the source and consuming/dependent code base?

A Spring Boot application will scan from the package the `SpringBootApplication` is placed in and any child packages.

If you have it within the same project, and your configuration class is structured that it is within the same package or a child package e.g.

`com.myapp` or `com.myapp.configs` it will be scanned and picked up.

When importing it to a different project you will need to manually component scan for the configuration via the `@ComponentScan` annotation and provide it with a package to scan for your configuration.

https://github.com/Flaw101/springbootmixin/tree/example/componentscanning

Because the `JacksonConfig.class` is in a parent (different) package the ComponentScan does not work. The Application class scans everything in `com.darrenforsythe.mixinabstractclass` and it's child packages. To make Spring Boot scan the `JacksonConfig` we have to be explicit and add the `@ComponentScan("com.darrenforsythe")` to the application.

If you uncomment the `@ComponentScan` within the `MixinasbtractclassApplication` the tests then pass again as it will load the `JacksonConfig` again.

Additionally, I would recommend using constructor. injection this would avoid the Autowired dependency being null and inform you on init of the ApplicationContext rather than at runtime.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, could you add some code in detail?

Comment: I agree, but I could not understand _I would recommend using instructor injection_ can you explain that?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera typo :) Meant constructor injection :)

Also updated with a working example in git.

Comment: my target project is not a spring boot framework, so what should i do in this situation

Comment: @yuwen-yan Unfortunately it won't work in that scenario.  Either the library you are providing is written with Dependency Injection in mind but can only work with Spring applications.  Otherwise you need to write your library in a standard Java way (e.g. Object myObject = new Object) and then it can be used by any Java application.

Comment: @YuwenYan please bare in mind that spring boot is built on top of the spring framework. Component Scanning, Beans etc. are all part of the basic spring framework. Configurations, Beans etc. are not dependent on using Spring Boot. I'd recommend reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that package in which the class available was scanned. Here is the annotation for that, put this annotation in SpringBoot application class.

```
@ComponentScan("com.abc.xyz")
```

Also, see if by any chance the class which has this autowired one is getting instantiated. If that class is instantied then ofcource the autowired ones will be null.